# windows power shell virus

Tags: windows, shell, virus

I'm running a web server windows server 2016 WebLogic and I keep seeing this PowerShell popup I've tried almost 20 third party antivirus but it is still appearing any one can help ?

[image: popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SysInternals' [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to see what might have snuck onto your system, and you can use it to disable anything suspicious.

That's as good a place to start as any.

Also, copy (Ctrl+C) and paste the text from that error message into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/m/translate) and post the English back to your question.  Thx.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the task manager and then to processes. Now cancel everything you're uncertain of the source of. If you're not sure something is supposed to be there, just google it to see if it's a windows process and if not then cancel it. They sometimes rename these viruses to adequately sounding things like "Windows Registry Handler" and etc. so be weary. After that go to the startup directory of the system and delete everything.

Comment: _Now cancel everything you're uncertain of the source of_ ... yeah, and potentially [bluescreen your system](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035).  It would be better to be a little more sure of your ground before posting.